# LaTeX: Multiple authors in a two-column article

Tags: layout, latex, tex

I'm kind of new to LaTeX and I am having a bit of a problem..

I am using a `twocolumn` layout for my `article`. There are four authors involved with different affiliations, and I am trying to list all of them under the title so they span the entire width of the page (all on the same level). It should be similar to this:

```
                  Article Title

auth1FN auth1LN     2  ... 3    auth4FN auth4LN
 department            ...        department
   school              ...          school
  email@edu            ...         email@edu


     Abstract                .....................
....................         .....................
....................         .....................
....................         .....................
```

Currently I have something along the lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\title{Article Title}
\author{
    First Last\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
  \and
    First Last\\
    ...
}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{multicols}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
...

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the authors are not displayed all on the same level, instead I get the first three next to each other, followed by the last one underneath.

Is there way to achieve what I want? Also if possible, how can I customize the font of the affiliations (to be smaller and in italic)?

Comment: It's most common, e.g., with the IEEE LNCS two-column style, to indicate affiliations with the `\thanks` macro, i.e., as footnotes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I put together a little test here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\title{Article Title}
\author{
    First Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
  \and
    Second Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Third Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Fourth Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\ldots
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\ldots

\end{document}
```

Things to note, the title, author and date fields are declared before `\begin{document}`.  Also, the multicol package is likely unnecessary in this case since you have declared `twocolumn` in the document class.

This example puts all four authors on the same line, but if your authors have longer names, departments or emails, this might cause it to flow over onto another line.  You might be able to change the font sizes around a little bit to make things fit.  This could be done by doing something like `{\small First Author}`.  Here's a more detailed article on `\LaTeX` font sizes:

https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/LaTeXChangingTheFont

To italicize you can use `{\it First Name}` or `\textit{First Name}`.

Be careful though, if the document is meant for publication often times journals or conference proceedings have their own formatting guidelines so font size trickery might not be allowed.

Comment: Unfortunately with the actual names in place, things still didn't fit on the same line. Its just a preference, but I guess I shouldn't try to interfere with the way LaTeX organizes the layout, Thanks anyway.
BTW defining `\title` and `\author` after `\begin{document}` works ok for me..

Comment: in my case the author names are not coming side by side, they are coming one below the other

Answer (score 12):

What about using a tabular inside `\author{}`, just like in IEEE macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Hello, World}
\author{
\begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\extracolsep{8em}}c} 
I. M. Author  & M. Y. Coauthor \\
My Department & Coauthor Department \\ 
My Institute & Coauthor Institute \\
email, address & email, address
\end{tabular}
}
\maketitle    
\end{document}
```

This will produce two columns authors with any `documentclass`.

Results:

[image]