# Add multiple authors to two columns in IEEEcsmag latex template

Tags: latex, ieee

In `IEEEcsmag`latex template, authors can be added as follows (default).

```
\documentclass{IEEEcsmag}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{upmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Title:...}

\author{F. A. Author}
\affil{First Affiliation}

\author{S. B. Author, Jr.}
\affil{Second Affiliation}

\author{T. C. Author, III}
\affil{Third Affiliation}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I need to add multiple authors in two columns and I've been trying for many days, but unable to find a proper solution. I have already tried `multicols` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041809/latex-multiple-authors-in-a-two-column-article) and `tabular` [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36471/writing-in-an-invisible-table), but none of them worked. Could anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Updated the latex code